# Kubernetes - How to assign label to all machinedeployment nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

We have created two machine deployments.

```
kubectl get machinedeployment -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                       REPLICAS   AVAILABLE-REPLICAS   PROVIDER   OS       KUBELET   AGE
kube-system   abc                        3          3                    hetzner    ubuntu   1.24.9    116m
kube-system   vnr4jdxd6s-worker-tgl65w   1          1                    hetzner    ubuntu   1.24.9    13d
```

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                                        STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
abc-b6647d7cb-bcprj                         Ready    <none>   62m   v1.24.9
abc-b6647d7cb-llsq8                         Ready    <none>   65m   v1.24.9
abc-b6647d7cb-mtlsl                         Ready    <none>   58m   v1.24.9
vnr4jdxd6s-worker-tgl65w-59ff7fc46c-d9tm6   Ready    <none>   13d   v1.24.9
```

We know that we can add a label to a specific node

```
kubectl label nodes abc-b6647d7cb-bcprj key=value
```

But our nodes are autoscaled.
We would like to install, for example, MariaDB Galera on specific machinedeployment node.
Is it somehow possible to annotate all nodes with a particular machinedeployments?

Is it somehow possible to annotate all nodes with a particular machinedeployments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To annotate all nodes with a particular machinedeployment. You can use the [kubectl annotate](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_annotate/) command to annotate all nodes in a particular machinedeployment with a specific key-value pair. For example, to annotate all nodes with a machinedeployment of nginx-deployment, you can run the following command:

```
kubectl annotate nodes --all deployment=nginx-deployment key=value
```

This will annotate all nodes in the machinedeployment of nginx-deployment with the specified key-value pair.

For more information follow this [blog by Seyi Ewegbemi](https://www.kubermatic.com/blog/annotating-machine-deployment-for-autoscaling/).